# Documentation Review filter based on tag option

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, documentation

It will be good if documentation review might have a filter by tag option, because IMO there is dilemma of whether contribution is good or bad of other tags, because some of them have good editing which gives the appearance as looks ok but unsure of content quality, because on tag creation SO asks for minimum 150 rep and +1 in their respective tag same must go when approving contribution.

Comment: We've just pushed an update that automatically filters by a tag if you're navigating to the review queue from a topic list or a tag's dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There already is, the "filter" link next to the title of the review.

[image]

As with other queues, you can enter up to three tags to filter on.

Also like other queues, if the change touches logic or explanation, and not just by rewording it for grammatical fixes, then it should be skipped if you don't *know* that it's correct. Regardless if that's a domain you know well or not, if the change isn't formatting, spelling corrections, or grammar fixes, reviewers should skip it and let someone who can confirm/deny the validity of the change handle it.